# PHP: Read file during upload

Tags: php, session, file-upload, upload, progress

I'm adding a file upload API to a web app written in PHP. I am able to get download progress using [PHP Session Upload Progress](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php).  The code I'm using is:

```
$key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") . $token;
if (!isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
    return -1;
}

return round(($_SESSION[$key]['bytes_processed'] / $_SESSION[$key]['content_length']) * 100, 1);
```

Which works well. The $_SESSION array includes information about the files being uploaded using the token given. One of the keys is 'tmp_name', but in my testing, it is never populated with a value until the upload is completed. This suggests to me that the upload in progress only exists in memory and is written to /tmp (or wherever the upload directory is configured to) when the upload is complete.

So my question then: Is there a way to access the file during upload? I'm expecting only CSVs right now and I would like to read the first line (the column headers) before the upload is complete.

Alternatively, other language/library suggestions are welcome, but relying on html5 (without fallback), flash, silverlight or java is not preferred.

Comment: PHP's upload mechanisms are incredibly stupid. Yes, it buffers the file in ram during the upload, instead of streaming it to disk. This is why PHP's `memory_limit` has to be larger than `upload_max_size` - because the file gets buffered in ram during the upload.

Comment: That makes sense (and I agree, I hate PHP file uploads). I imagine that memory access would be unsafe at best and not allowed at worst.

Comment: yeah, it'd be doable, e.g via /proc access to the process image, but you'd have a very hard time figuring out exactly WHERE in the process's image that the upload data actually lives.

Comment: So that's a non-starter. I did find [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CEkQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webiny.com%2Fblog%2F2012%2F05%2F07%2Fwebiny-file-upload-with-html5-and-ajax-using-php-streams%2F&ei=ZLzeUti9NpGGogT14YDwBg&usg=AFQjCNGe4zJG540peRFXGTEagdxE7MY9jw&sig2=JJcps8sjhA2i5Il7GjekyQ&bvm=bv.59568121,d.cGU) which would work, but I would still need a fallback for the people stuck on old browsers.